# MongoDB: I'm using find() to get a specific value but instead getting multiple results

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Working on a Facebook clone and I'm setting up uploading a profile picture. I have a `User` schema with a `profilePicture` object. The user visits the page, uploads a picture and that image URL gets added to their `profilePicture` value.

`User` schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  profilePicture: String,
});
```

Here's an example of what a User looks like in the DB.

```
_id: 642716b83w306234dx8d6cab
username: "Dagger"
profilePicture: "public\images\uploads\a7c770ff72d830a4fb0c8f6963ab9aa8"
```

And here is the GET request for my profilePicture. What I'm doing is using `User.find()` to find the profilePicture

```
router.get("/:user/profile-picture", (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, "profilePicture").exec(function (err, profilePicture) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.render("picture", { user, id, picture, profilePicture });
  });
});
```

but when I add the `img` code to the ejs page nothing shows up.

```
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="<%= profilePicture %>.jpg" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

When I inspect the element I notice the value of `<%= profilePicture %>` is a list of **every** User in my database. How can I narrow it down so I only get the value set to `"public\images\uploads\a7c770ff72d830a4fb0c8f6963ab9aa8"`?

Comment: Use `findOne` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `findOne()` and specify the parameter you want to search by.

For Example:

```
User.findOne({ username: 'Dagger'}, "profilePicture").exec(...)
```

Being that you want it dynamic, you'd need to replace the hardcoded `'Dagger'` value I use here with a variable so you can identify which user's photo to pull.

Comment: Thank you. This worked to narrow it down to just my user using `username: user` but the URL is still a bit wonky.  `/public/images/uploads/{
  _id: new ObjectId("647716b83b306234d78d6cab"),
  profilePicture: 'public\\images\\uploads\\a7c770ff72d830a4fb0c8f6963ab9aa8'
}.jpeg`. Is this normal? EDIT: Never mind I may have fixed it. I changed it to `<%= profilePicture.profilePicture %>`